# RoR : persisting data on button click

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am stuck with persisting data on button click. Is it possible to get the parameters to different controller function from another page.

## Controller

```
def create
  @login=Login.new
  @login.name=params[:name]
  @login.email=params[:email]
  @login.password=params[:password]
  @login.phone_number=params[:phone_number]

  if @login.save
        render :action => 'success'
  else
   puts (@login.errors.full_messages)
       render :action => 'failure'
  end

end

def operation
if params[:commit] == "Clicked"
    puts ("Inside CLICKED")
    redirect_to action: 'clicked'
else
    redirect_to action: 'create'
end
end
```

## view (create.html.erb)

```
 <h1>Welcome to DemoSite.com</h1>
 <p></p>

 <%= form_for (@login), :url => {:action => "create"} do |f| %>
 <p>
   <%= f.label :Name %><br>
   <%= f.text_field :name %>
 </p>

 <p>
  <%= f.label :Email %><br>
  <%= f.text_field :email %>
 </p>

 <p>
  <%= f.label :Phone_Number %><br>
  <%= f.telephone_field :phone_number %>
 </p>

 <p>
  <%= f.label :Password %><br>
  <%= f.password_field :password %>
 </p>

 <p>
  <%= f.label :password_confirmation %><br>
  <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation %>
 </p>

 <p>
  <%= f.submit('Submit') %>
 </p> 
<% end %>
```

## index.html.erb

```
<h1>Welcome to DemoSite.com</h1>
<p></p>

<%= form_tag "/logins/operation", :method => "post"  do %>
<p>
  <%= label_tag(:username, "Username") %><br>
  <%= text_field_tag(:username) %>
</p>
<p>
  <%= label_tag(:password, "Password") %><br>
  <%= password_field_tag(:password) %>
</p>

<p>
 <%=submit_tag "Create" %> 
 <%= submit_tag "Clicked" %> 
</p>
```

When I run this, it directs me to *failure.html.erb* directly from index.html.erb when I click **create button**, without hitting the *create.html.erb*. Also, how can I persist the data inside `create` method after button click?

Comment: Do you have a view page `success.html.erb` in your view pages?

Comment: yes..i have..when i remove all the validations..i get the success page..but why am i not seeing create.html page..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `operation` action redirects to `create` and your `create` action either renders failure or succes, your create action never does the default thing (namely rendering your create-view).

Most of the times the `new` action renders the form, and the `create` action (which should be POST) actually creates (saves) the data.

The redirect to create as you do it now, will never succeed, because it will not receive any data, so it will always fail to create the user, so it will always show the failure screen.

[UPDATE] simplest (but still dirty way) to fix it :

If you redirect to your `create` action, it is a GET request, not POST.

So the simplest fix is this:

```
def create
  if request.post?
    @login = Login.new(params)

    if @login.save
      render :action => 'success'
    else
      puts (@login.errors.full_messages)
      render :action => 'failure'
    end
  else
    @login = Login.new
  end
end
```

So if it is a `POST`: try to save and check the errors. If it is a GET just render the `create.html.erb`.

The best, clean REST way, is to redirect to the `new` action from your `operation` action, and your form will POST to the `create` action. This is how it is supposed to be.

Comment: But I thought when I would goto index page and click create button. It will goto create action and renders the create.html.erb and then when I hit the submit button, create action itself persists the data and checks for errors. what change should I make to achieve that, if I want to keep the same design as of now? Is it possible? Thanks

Comment: thanks for the edit and worked for me but yes I will change the design for sure and add the new action in the controller.